# Why jPanel doesn't clear?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

This program draws an oval of the inputted size on a **jPanel**. When i change the size of drawn circle, the old one doesn't disappear. Why?

code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

    jPanel.Repaint();
    try{
        jLabel6.setText("");
        int a=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()); 

        Graphics2D gfx=(Graphics2D)jPanel1.getGraphics();
        gfx.setColor(Color.red);
        gfx.fillOval(100,50,a,a);
        gfx.fillOval(400,50,a,a);

    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        jLabel6.setText("Incorrect data");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use overridden [JPanel#paintComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method instead of using `JPanel#getGraphics()` method.

**Don't** forget to call `super.paintComponent(g);` in overridden `paintComponent()` method.

```
JPanel jPanel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(100, 50, c, c);
        g.fillOval(400, 50, c, c);
    }
};
```

---

--EDIT--

Changes in your code:

```
// This is the code where you have create JPanel object
JPanel jPanel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        try{
            int c=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());//read the value

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(100, 50, c, c);
            g.fillOval(400, 50, c, c);

        }catch(NumberFormatException e){//handle the exception} 
    }
};


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

    try{
        jLabel6.setText("");
        jPanel.repaint(); // simply call repaint method
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        jLabel6.setText("Incorrect data");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `gfx.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());` in your code before new drawing.

Comment: Call above line just after `Graphics2D gfx=(Graphics2D)jPanel1.getGraphics();`

Comment: +1 but getWidth(), getHeight() works correctly in the case that getPreferredSize is override for JPanel, otherwise result could be pretty zero Dimansion (default value)

Comment: @mKorbel Yes you are right. Thanks again. Can I pass any random high value? Is there any drawback in it?